# Remove $ Sign from importXML formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an issue with the IMPORTXML function and then changing the currency in my portfolio tracker.

IMPORTXML (C3=IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']") takes the price of a cryptocurrency from coinmarketcap (B3=https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/ - this all works fine (would rather prefer to have the prices from coingecko, but cannot figure the IMPORTXML function for that website... - if anyone has some valuable input for this too, would be great).

However, the imported price in C3 has a dollar sign before the actual numbers, which mess up the GOOGLEFINANCE formulas in columns D (D3=C3*GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDEUR")) and E (E3=C3*GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDGBP")). Screenshot of the error attached. [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OqBg.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Much appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the imported price in C3 has a dollar sign in front of the actual numbers, which breaks down further processing by formulas.
To solve the problem, you can wrap the formula in C3 in a MID() formula that returns a segment of a string. If we specify a position number equal to 2, starting from which the string segment will be extracted, then the dollar sign at position 1 will be ignored. The sign of the pound or the euro will also be ignored - any currency sign with a length of 1 symbol.

10 is the segment length with some margin. Please note if the end of string is reached before segment length characters are encountered, MID returns the characters from starting position to the end of string.

C3:

```
=MID(IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"),2,10)
```

**[MID()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en)**

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

On cell `C3` you could use:

> `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"),"$",""))`

### References:

- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little workaround to import the prices from coingecko, and remove the $ simbol, of course:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum"; "//div[contains(@data-controller,'coins-information')]//span[contains(@data-coin-symbol,'eth')]");"$";"")
```

But, as you can imagine, if they change the html structure of the site, this will stop working.

Have fun!